# 16/3 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored , 16/3 PLS-00394: wrong number of values in the INTO list of a FETCH statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I try to execute below code I got above error. This is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_ref_value(orderId IN orders.order_id%TYPE)
IS
ref_value   NUMBER;
CURSOR c2 (orderId orders.order_id%TYPE) IS 
SELECT order_id,
    CASE 
    WHEN   order_status='refunded' THEN total_order*0.25
    WHEN   order_status='completed' THEN  total_order* 0
    WHEN   order_status='cancelled' THEN total_order*0
    END 
    FROM orders;

BEGIN
    OPEN c2(orderId);
    LOOP
        FETCH c2 INTO ref_value;
        EXIT WHEN c2%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ref_value);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c2;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems pretty clear, but here is an elaboration.

Your cursor is defined as:

```
SELECT order_id,
       (CASE WHEN order_status='refunded' THEN total_order*0.25 
             WHEN order_status='completed' THEN total_order* 0 
             WHEN order_status='cancelled' THEN total_order*0 
        END)
FROM orders;
```

This returns TWO columns -- `order_id` and the expression result.

Your `FETCH` is defined as:

```
FETCH c2 INTO ref_value;
```

This tries to put the results into ONE column.

Either change the cursor definition to remove `order_id` or change the `FETCH` to include two parameters.

Then, after this runs, you'll probably get an error because your cursor has no parameters but you are trying to pass one in.